# How is memory handled when calling the `extend` and `drain` methods from Vec and VecDeque?

Tags: rust, vector, memory-management, deque

In Rust, do the methods `extend` and `drain` from Vec and VecDeque copy the contents of the items, or are the items moved in like in a list?

Consider that `reserve` reserve has been called prior, and that the Vec/VecDeque already have space for the elements.

Edit: For clarification, what happens, at memory level, with the following code? Are the contents copied from Vec to VecDeque, or is there simply a change in pointers like removing/inserting in a linked list?

```
let mut a: Vec<i32> = (0..10).collect();
let mut b: VecDeque<i32> = VecDeque::new();
b.reserve(10);

b.extend(a.drain(..));
```

Comment: The documentation is usually very specific about this, as in [for `drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec-drain.html).

Comment: @tadman I have read the linked page and still don't understand if a copy happens or not. Which part of the page you linked could help me understand this?

Comment: Phrasing like "it borrows the Vec and leaves its allocation untouched".

Comment: There is no `expand()` method for `Vec` or `VecDeque` (there is `extend()` though). The elements drained are removed from the vector, I don't understand your question.

Comment: If with *'like in a list'* you mean they stay at their memory location, then the answer is no. Putting something into or out of a `Vec`/`VecDeque` most certainly will move that item from one memory location to another.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Corrected and added details.

Comment: @Finomnis Copy does not invole `Clone`. It is always a bitwise copy.

Comment: @Finomnis Try it. It does not work.

Comment: I can strongly recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDoqT-a6UFg), for me it clarified a lot of the memory details in std data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of `a` and `b` are on fixed locations in memory. Because `b` already has enough capacity, a reallocation of `b` won't happen.

The data itself, though, will be memcopied from `a` to `b`, and `a` will be marked empty afterwards.

---

To demonstrate, here is a little program that shows the inner state of a `Vec` during such a process:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

macro_rules! dbg_vec {
    ($v: ident) => {
        dbg_vec_impl(stringify!($v), &$v);
    };
}

fn dbg_vec_impl<T: Debug>(name: &str, v: &Vec<T>) {
    println!(
        "Vec '{}': ({:p}, {}, {})",
        name,
        v.as_ptr(),
        v.len(),
        v.capacity()
    );
    println!("    Real content:   {:?}", v);
    unsafe {
        println!(
            "    Memory content: {:?}",
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(v.as_ptr(), v.capacity())
        )
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = (0..10).collect();
    let mut b: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    dbg_vec!(a);
    dbg_vec!(b);

    b.reserve(10);
    println!("\nb.reserve(10);\n");

    dbg_vec!(a);
    dbg_vec!(b);

    b.extend(a.drain(..));
    println!("\nb.extend(a.drain(..))\n");

    dbg_vec!(a);
    dbg_vec!(b);

    a.shrink_to_fit();
    b.shrink_to_fit();
    println!("\nshrink_to_fit()\n");

    dbg_vec!(a);
    dbg_vec!(b);
}
```

```
Vec 'a': (0x1e932d5deb0, 10, 10)
    Real content:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    Memory content: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Vec 'b': (0x4, 0, 0)
    Real content:   []
    Memory content: []

b.reserve(10);

Vec 'a': (0x1e932d5deb0, 10, 10)
    Real content:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    Memory content: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Vec 'b': (0x1e932d5dd60, 0, 10)
    Real content:   []
    Memory content: [5439557, 5505099, 5242959, 7667773, 6553710, 6684773, 7209065, 6553701, 5177344, 3997779]

b.extend(a.drain(..))

Vec 'a': (0x1e932d5deb0, 0, 10)
    Real content:   []
    Memory content: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Vec 'b': (0x1e932d5dd60, 10, 10)
    Real content:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    Memory content: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

shrink_to_fit()

Vec 'a': (0x4, 0, 0)
    Real content:   []
    Memory content: []
Vec 'b': (0x1e932d5dd60, 10, 10)
    Real content:   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    Memory content: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Vec` and `VecDeque` are not a linked lists, and are not operating list linked lists. They're contiguous in memory, so yes, a bitwise copy happen. The semantics of the copy may be a copy or a move, depending on whether the type implements `Copy`.